# Count the number of days in a specified dates with real time update

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have used the below formula to get the pending days count with real time update. But it does not works well. 
[image: Image for reference]
I have used vba to count only the cells which does not have color. The XFD cell is blank cell to set a criteria of counting only the blank cell.
The challenge is in excluding back dated days in real time.

```
=(CountCellsByColor($B2:$AL2,$XFD$1))-(TODAY()-$B$1)
```

VBA given below:

```
Function CountCellsByColor(rData As Range, cellRefColor As Range) As Long
    Dim indRefColor As Long
    Dim cellCurrent As Range
    Dim cntRes As Long

    Application.Volatile
    cntRes = 0
    indRefColor = cellRefColor.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color
    For Each cellCurrent In rData
        If indRefColor = cellCurrent.Interior.Color Then
            cntRes = cntRes + 1
        End If
    Next cellCurrent

    CountCellsByColor = cntRes
End Function
```

Comment: what is the expected output? how does the vba definition look like? (pls add vba tag too)

Comment: Added VBA tag too

Comment: Q: What do you mean by "real time update"? What is "indRefColor" - "red", "yellow" or "something else?  What do you expect "cntRes" to be?  The sum of all red and yellow boxes?  What is "cntRed" instead? Could you please clarify?

Comment: "Real time update" Means whenever the excel workbook is open, it will not include the back dated days as of "Today()" in counting. Do not have much knowledge on the VBA coding, since it's been copied from internet.

Comment: if you just run `=CountCellsByColor($B2:$AL2,$XFD$1)` is the result = 18 ?

Comment: @p._phidot_ Yes!

Comment: Since "The challenge is in excluding backdated days in real-time".. then what is your expected value (if it is not 10) ?

Comment: @p._phidot_ The expected output is 8 days, considering today is 20th Jan 2020.

Comment: Ok I get it.. but is W2 cell included or excluded in the count ?

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming that the current day cell is not included. )

TLDR : add match & offset in your formula.

If the date entered is formatted as date (not a text), then use :

```
=CountCellsByColor($B2:$AL2,$XFD$1)-CountCellsByColor(OFFSET($B2,0,0,1,MATCH(today(),$B1:$AL1,0)),$XFD$1)
```

Hope it helps. ( :

Comment: Errata : I had corrected the match() formula to cover range `$B1:$AL1` instead of the (wrong,original) `$B2:$AL2`. If the solution works. you may click on the 'tick' to remove this question from the unanswered list. ( :